# Arrange data frame reversed order

Tags: r, sorting, plyr

I have a data frame which I want to order (not alphabetically) so I wrote this

```
z
  Grupos prueba$pendiente
1     TR         12.48182
2 TR2x45         39.87879
3     UT         20.89545
4 UT2x45         36.89015
orden
[1] "UT"     "TR"     "UT2x45" "TR2x45"
z<-arrange(z,orden)
z
  Grupos prueba$pendiente
1 TR2x45         39.87879
2 UT2x45         36.89015
3     TR         12.48182
4     UT         20.89545
```

> dput(z)
>   structure(list(Grupos = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("UT", 
>   "TR", "UT2x45", "TR2x45"), class = "factor"), `prueba$pendiente` = c(39.8787878787918, 
>   36.8901515151553, 12.4818181818195, 20.8954545454566)), .Names = c("Grupos", 
>   "prueba$pendiente"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

Arrange function is working, the only problem is I got the wrong order (reversed) I want UT to be my first value just like in `orden` vector.
I'm sure it's a quite silly thing but I can't work it out.

Thank you

Comment: see last example of `?arrange`, but note that it's not meant to mix columns from the data.frame and other vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `decreasing = TRUE` to `arrange`

```
> arrange(z, orden, decreasing = TRUE)
##   Grupos prueba.pendiente
## 1     UT         20.89545
## 2     TR         12.48182
## 3 UT2x45         36.89015
## 4 TR2x45         39.87879
```

Alternatively, you could re-factor `Grupos` and use the `order` function to "subset" the order.

```
> z$Grupos <- factor(z$Grupos, levels = orden)
> z[order(z$Grupos), ]
##   Grupos prueba.pendiente
## 3     UT         20.89545
## 1     TR         12.48182
## 4 UT2x45         36.89015
## 2 TR2x45         39.87879
```

Comment: The first option doesn't work. I've tried it before asking here but I think the problem is there's no increasing or decreasing order for my arbitrary vector named orden. The second one works, thank you

Comment: @MatiasAndina the fact that `z$Grupos` was already a factor wasn't apparent in your first edit, so it's not surprising that some proposed solutions "didn't work", they were solving a different problem.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry!! I should have posted it with dput the first time. It was clear for me that they're factors because I'm preparing to use it that way. I should have asked better.

Comment: @MatiasAndina, glad it worked.  I'm curious, when you read in the data, did you use the `stringsAsFactors` argument?

Comment: @RichardScriven I don't read this data from anywhere, I just constructed it from another data frame using aggregate. Each number that you see in the second column is the mean of many measurements of each factor from a bigger data frame

Answer (score 2):

The top accepted answer doesn't work if your haven't applied factors to your data. Instead a much better general approach is to add `desc()` or `-` to your data values variable.

So in your case it would look something like:

`z = arrange(z, -desc(orden))`
or
`z = arrange(z, -orden)`

Further information and examples can be found in the [source documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
z[order(orden,decreasing=TRUE),]
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Besides decreasing=TRUE doesn't have any logic, the order I want to give is arbitrary

Comment: Works just fine given the data you provided. If you encounter errors with proposed solutions, consider giving us a bit more information so we can better diagnose the issue (e.g. dput, str, etc.).

Comment: I'm sorry, really my bad

Comment: Don't worry about it - no big deal! :)

Answer (score 0):

you could just reverse the order of `orden`

```
arrange(z,rev(orden))
```

Comment: it works perfectly on the test data frame I created. Maybe you should think about adding a sample of your data using `dput()` to work why these solutions are not working for you

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the simple base function `match`

```
z[match(orden, z$Grupos),]
```